# Linq Select query which returns a task enumerates multiple times

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a linq query which returns a task object and stores it in an `IEnumerable`. For some reason the select query keeps enumerating until the task is started or finished (I think, it's hard to debug).

The query is pretty straight forward:

```
Context.RetrieveDataTasks = retrievableProducts.Select(product => Context.HostController.RetrieveProductDataFiles(product));
```

Where the signature for `RetrieveProductDataFiles` is :

```
public Task RetrieveProductDataFiles(IProduct product)
```

The retrievableProducts is in this case a list of 1 product:

```
var retrievableProducts = products
    .Where(product => AFancyButIrrelevantClause)
    .ToList();
```

I don't mind to rewrite the code to a foreach loop where I fill a new list manually to avoid this problem, but I'd like to understand **why** the select query keeps executing. I think it has something to do with the task which is waiting for activation, but I have no idea why that would cause this.

Edit:

Just to be complete, I'd expect that above code works exactly the same as :

```
var retrievableDataTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var product in retrievableProducts)
{
    retrievableDataTasks.Add(Context.HostController.RetrieveProductDataFiles(product));
}
Context.RetrieveDataTasks = retrievableDataTasks;
```

While the construction with a `foreach` does exactly what I expect: it populates a list with tasks (in this specific case a list of 1 task) and this task is executed once. While in the construction with the `Select` query that same 1 task is started over and over again.

I hope it's clear enough with the code I provided, looking forward to learn why the select query behaves differently (and if possible, how to avoid it from happening).

Comment: Your where command is running? The AFancyButIrrelevantClause is a Boolean variable?

Comment: It's your ToList that's causing this. ToList forces your enumeration (IEnumerable) to concretely instanciate a List, which has an array underneath, with all its content. Instead of lazily going over your collection until your task is done, you going through everything even though it's all done. Refactor without using to list, and you'll be able to leverage the usage of 'yield break' that will stop the enumerator from going forward once your work is done, even though there are more than a million or billion elements that hasn't been seen yet.

Comment: @KevinAvignon I think I already found it, but I don't understand what you are saying. I changed the type of the `Context.RetrieveDataTasks` property from IEnumerable<Task> to List<Task>. The reason why the task kept starting was that every time I iterate `Context.RetrieveDataTasks` the select query gets executed.

Comment: Look at my answer, there won't be any need to use a List collection in your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to the posted question is by "bas" himself. Every time you reference the IEnumerable it re-evaluates the expression inside of "Select" and thus starts the tasks again. "ToList" would actually fix the problem because it would stop evaluating them.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'ToList' forces the iterator to iterate through all the collection, even though you think you said 'simply give me the first two items in the collection'. If that said collection has 1000 elements, you'll iterate on that collection until you've reached the last item, and it'll still give you 2 elements.

> You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or LINQ query. Each iteration of the foreach loop calls the iterator method. When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.

In your method where you instantiate a list where you add to it, you'd need to improve a little to use yield returns and thus, not allocate data that doesn't need to be allocated. LINQ methods are lazy evaluated, which means that there won't be any memory allocation for data until you try to materialize the results (ToList for instance). While you're in your LINQ method, the only memory usage you get is for the current iteration, not for everything that's found in your collection.

Let's say use the following code snippet to help you.

```
private static IEnumerable<Product> GetMyProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products, bool AFancyButIrrelevantClause)
{
   foreach(var product in products)
   {
       if(AFancyButIrrelevantClause)
           yield return product;
    }
 }
```

or directly in LINQ to be more concise:

```
 products.Where(product => AFancyButIrrelevantClause)
```